# How can I interpret the P-value of nonlinear term under rms: anova?

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression, cubic-spline

Here I demonstrated a survival model with rcs term. I was wondering whether the anova()under rms package is the way to test the linearity association? And How can I interpret the P-value of the Nonlinear term (see 0.094 here), does that support adding a rcs() term in the cox model?

```
library(rms)
data(pbc)
d <- pbc
rm(pbc, pbcseq)
d$status <- ifelse(d$status != 0, 1, 0)
dd = datadist(d)
options(datadist='dd')

# rcs model
m2 <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~  rcs(albumin, 4), data=d)
anova(m2)

Wald Statistics      Response: Surv(time, status) 
Factor     Chi-Square d.f. P     
albumin    82.80      3    <.0001
Nonlinear   4.73      2    0.094 
TOTAL      82.80      3    <.0001
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to test is with model comparison of the log-likelihood (aka deviance) across two models: a full and reduced:

```
m2 <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~  rcs(albumin, 4), data=d)
anova(m2)
m <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~  albumin, data=d)

p.val <- 1- pchisq( (m2$loglik[2]- m$loglik[2]), 2 )
```

You can see the difference in the inference using the less accurate Wald statistic (which in your case was not significant anyway since the p-value was > 0.05) versus this more accurate method in the example that Harrell used in his ?cph help page. Using his example:

```
> anova(f)
                Wald Statistics          Response: S 

 Factor     Chi-Square d.f. P     
 age        57.75      3    <.0001
  Nonlinear  8.17      2    0.0168
 sex        18.75      1    <.0001
 TOTAL      75.63      4    <.0001
```

You would *incorrectly* conclude that the nonlinear term was "significant" at conventional 0.05 level. This despite the fact that code creating the model was constructed as entirely linear in age (on the log-hazard scale):

```
h <- .02*exp(.04*(age-50)+.8*(sex=='Female'))
```

Create a reduced mode and compare:

```
f0 <- cph(S ~ age + sex, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
anova(f0)
#-------------
                 Wald Statistics          Response: S 

 Factor     Chi-Square d.f. P     
 age        56.64      1    <.0001
 sex        16.26      1    1e-04 

 TOTAL      75.85      2    <.0001
```

The difference in deviance is not significant with 2 degrees of freedom difference:

```
1-pchisq((f$loglik[2]- f0$loglik[2]),2)
[1] 0.1243212
```

I don't know why Harrell leaves this example in, because I've taken his RMS course and know that he endorses the cross-model comparison of deviance as the more accurate approach.