# How to predict ln(odds) with rcs term in mixed effects logistic model?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4, mixed-models, spline

I am using "lme4" package to fit mixed-effects nonlinear logistic model to access the association of Y and X. As the response variable of my data is binary and nlmer function requires response variable to be continuous, I use glmer function and "rms" package function rcs to fit the model and visualize the nonlinear association like the R code below:

```
library(lme4)
library(rms)
m <- glmer(r2 ~ rcs(Anger, 5) + Gender + situ + btype + (1 | id), 
           data = VerbAgg, family = binomial("logit"),
           control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
p <- predict(m, newdata = VerbAgg, type = "link")
scatter.smooth(VerbAgg$Anger,p,pch='.',col="blue",lpars=list(type="l",col="red"))
```

I have some questions about using this code:

1. Is the code correct?
2. How to predict the ln(Odds) of r2? Is it "p <- predict(m, newdata =
   VerbAgg, type = "link")" ?
3. How to visualize the spline of ln(Odds) of r2 and Anger? Is it
   correct to use "scatter.smooth" function to plot and add a smooth
   curve in scatters?
4. How to get the P-nonlinear for this model?

Comment: You should keep your posts to one question each—you might want to split this into separate posts per major question. Whether code is correct might depend on what you're trying to do exactly, not just a yes or no. Some of what you're asking is more appropriate on [stats.se]; questions here should be specific to programming, not stats interpretation

Comment: What is "P-nonlinear" ? Can you give a definition or a link?

Comment: Thank you @camille, I had asked these questions on Cross Validated.

Comment: did you cross-post? If so, could you post the link?

Comment: it is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555409/how-to-predict-lnodds-with-rcs-term-in-mixed-effects-logistic-model/557349#557349)

Comment: Please don't cross-post, it wastes time and energy for everyone since your questions get answered by different people in different places ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It looks reasonable.
2. Yes. Just `predict(m)` should give you the predicted log-odds for each observation (since `predict` uses the original data by default, and `type = "link"` is also the default).  (But being more explicit doesn't hurt.)
3. You could construct a data frame that has the baseline value for the non-focal predictors and `Anger` spanning an appropriate range of values, then use that as `newdata` in a `predict` call. Or you could use the `emmeans` or `effects` packages, both of which try to automate this process for you.

This worked for me (natural splines with `ns` seem to integrate better with `lme4` than `rcs`)

```r
library(lme4)
library(effects)
m <- glmer(r2 ~ splines::ns(Anger, df = 5) + Gender + situ + btype + (1 | id), 
           data = VerbAgg, family = binomial("logit"),
           control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
plot(Effect("Anger", m)
```

You can do a significance test of the spline term by using `car::Anova()` or by model comparison (likelihood ratio test):

```r
m0 <- update(m, r2 ~ Gender + situ + btype + (1 | id))
anova(m, m0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! The P-nonliear question had been anwsered in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937065/how-can-i-interpret-the-p-value-of-nonlinear-term-under-rms-anova), but I am not sure weather it is correct to perform a log-likelihood test across the full model and reduced model to get the P value.